# nonblocking stack in java

Tags: java, multithreading, compare-and-swap

Can somebody help me in writing a **non-blocking, lock free** `stack` implementation. Is it there in the Sun java implementation?

I was trying to write a thread safe `Stack` by putting a global lock on the whole stack data structure (it is costly) but it seems that it is possible to write a **non-blocking, lock free**  stack.

An algorithm is called nonblocking if it is lock free and immune of deadlock.

Comment: With facility, there comes responsibility. While users on SO are always there to help, a little google & analysis of result(s) is a must.

Comment: please reopen the question i have rephrased the question. Thanks.

Comment: This https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/index.html excellent article provides the solution for nonblocking stack.

Comment: This is a relevant question, to which I got directed by Googling specifically for this, and I find it wrong that it is locked. It is not a "school assignment" question, and the answer about ConcurrentLinkedQueue is totally off base to the rather specific and interesting question.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MyConcurrentStack<T> {

    private AtomicReference<Node> head = new AtomicReference<Node>();

    public MyConcurrentStack() {
    }

    public void push(T t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node<T> n = new Node<T>(t);
        Node<T> current;

        do {
            current = head.get();
            n.setNext(current);
        } while (!head.compareAndSet(current, n));
    }

    public T pop() {
        Node<T> currentHead = null;
        Node<T> futureHead = null;
        do {
            currentHead = head.get();
            if (currentHead == null) {
                return null;
            }
            futureHead = currentHead.next;
        } while (!head.compareAndSet(currentHead, futureHead));

        return currentHead.data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return null if no element present else return a element. it does not
     * remove the element from the stack.
     */
    public T peek() {
        Node<T> n = head.get();
        if (n == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return n.data;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (head.get() == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {

        private final T data;
        private Node<T> next;

        private Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        private void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**concurrent stack java first google result**

> Queues
>
> The java.util.concurrent [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) class supplies an
>   efficient scalable thread-safe non-blocking FIFO queue. Five
>   implementations in java.util.concurrent support the extended
>   [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface, that defines blocking versions of put
>   and take: [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html),
>   [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html), and
>   [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html). The different classes cover the most common usage
>   contexts for producer-consumer, messaging, parallel tasking, and
>   related concurrent designs. The BlockingDeque interface extends
>   BlockingQueue to support both FIFO and LIFO (stack-based) operations.
>   Class LinkedBlockingDeque provides an implementation.

Comment: OP is asking about stack i.e. LIFO.

Comment: read again `The BlockingDeque interface extends BlockingQueue to support both FIFO and LIFO (stack-based) operations. Class LinkedBlockingDeque provides an implementation.`

Comment: `LinkedBlockingDeque` is not a implementation that i want. i want non blocking and lock free implementation, which `LinkedBlockingDeque` is not. @Trying has give the closest answer but i still waiting if something else is also possible. Thanks.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue implements FIFO, while LIFI is needed, and LinkedBlockingDequeue is blocking, while non-blocking is needed.